# Some integer does not have a square root in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if $n \geq 3$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

**Some integer does not have a square root in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if $n \geq 3$.**

I am having difficulty showing this. Can someone provide minimal guidance, or a small hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider Prime Numbers.

Comment: Have you tried writing down all the squares in, say, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and seeing what happens? Try it for several other values of $n$.

Comment: Maybe some integer has two square roots?

Comment: alright, Thanks guys :)

Comment: Either $n$ is divisible by a prime $p\geq 3$ or $n$ is divisible by $4.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $S:x \mapsto x^2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not injective because $S(x)=S(-x)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is finite, $S$ cannot be surjective.